# Varnish cache top navigation menu

Tags: frontend, varnish

Well first of all We have using the Porto theme and using the mega menu. we currently running magento 2.2.3.

It's seems that when we Enabled varnish on my Current Magento and configure everything that it's working except can't display navigation menu. kindly help me 
Advance Thank you

Comment: if you paid for this theme you have to ask their support, i know they have a solution.